# std::atomic<> for avr-gcc

Tags: c++, interrupt, avr, avr-gcc, stdatomic

I wonder if it would be possible to write `std::atomic<>` for the use on the AVR µC. The
`__atomic_xxx()` built-ins are unfortunately not implemented in avr-gcc.

As I understand basic load/store of `uint8_t` on AVR is atomic, but e.g. `operator++()` not because it implies an rmw-cycle. So, for these operations one has to disable interrupts, because this is the only form of concurrency on this hardware. For larger types than `uint8_t` even the `operator=(T)` needs to be protected from interrupts.

On the other hand one has to apply a memory-barrier to the data member of the `std::atomic<>` template: e.g. this data member has the name `value` one has to use
`asm volatile("" : "+m" (value));` to accomplish real load/stores on the machine.

Is this sufficient to implement the `std::atomic<>`?

Because this implementation is lock-free, it should be useable for ISRs on that hardware.

If one would implement such `std::atomic<>` this would led to unefficient machine code *inside* the ISR, because the unneccessary interrupt disabling and/or the memory-barrier, which prevents optimization.

Well, this could be circumvented by extending the interface of the `std::atomic<>` with *unsafe* operations.

On the other hand: would it be more feasable to implement `std::atomic_ref<>` and use this outside the ISR?

Comment: Using `asm volatile ("" : "+m" (value));` would be sufficient for `relaxed` atomic operations, and it shouldn't do unnecessary harm to optimization because operations on other variables can be moved and optimized around it.  But for acquire/release or stronger ordering, you would need `asm volatile("" : : : "memory");` to get a full compiler barrier.

Comment: I guess a lazy way to get "unsafe" operations would be the reverse of `atomic_ref`: a member function that just returns a reference to the object as an ordinary non-atomic  `int&` or whatever.  In practice you can probably get this already with a simple type cast.